# Save the content of <a href> in the localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, local-storage

I want to save the content of the `<a href>` In the localstorage and reuse it. How can i do that? I want to keep the link working. I want to use it to link to webapps (user provided) and i want to achieve that with the localstorage (i am building an online os For personal(and maybe) public use it won't be as big like eyeos or jolicloud).

Comment: Signatures / "Thank you, .." shouldn't be added to a question/reply (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the whole link (including attributes):

```
<script>
function setLinks(){
     var all_links = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
     localStorage.setItem("savedLinkHTML", all_links);
}
function getLinks(){
    var all_links = localStorage.getItem("savedLinkHTML");
    if(all_links) document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = all_links;
}
window.onload = function(){
    getLinks();
}
window.onunload = function(){
    setLinks();
}
</script>
 ...
<div id="savedLinks"></div>
```

You can create your own functions to dynamically add more links (even images) to the container, which are automatically saved when leaving the page, and shown again when visiting the page.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: It seems to me that the OP wants to save the value of the *href* property, not a big slab of HTML. There is a [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection that can help with that.

Comment: `document.links` refers to all links within a document. `document.getElementById("savedLinks").getElementsByTagName("a")` does only refer to the links within the container. It's not hard to adjust the code, to only store the label and the link. I believe that the OP is having issues with saving the data.

Comment: Using `getElementsByTagName('a')` will return all A elements, which might be anchors or links (or both). It is also a function call rather than direct property access so slower (which is probably irrelevant as users won't notice the difference unless there is a very large number of them). My take on the question was to store the *herf* values, yours was different. Seems the OP hasn't been back, so moot at this poin. :-)

Comment: Notice that I suggested using the `document.getElementsByTageName` method on the container element, to restrict the number of links.

Comment: How can I use it with images?

Comment: @Dev1.developper Could you post a fiddle with your HTML structure in the comments?

Comment: sorry but on my phone can't use jfiddle now

Answer (score 0):

Why not just grab the URL

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

and then store it in the value for key(i)?  I know that sounds too simple, but that is what you are asking... isn't it?  You would just need a naming system for retrieval.